# How to minify/compress WebResource.axd?

Tags: asp.net, compression, minify, webresource.axd

I started a personal project to look for ways to improve the performance of my already made webpages (wish I never mark this as a personal goal :S).

I've been looking for a tool to help me minify the webresource.axd file generated by ASP.NET Framework 4.5.

I've tried some solutions (MbCompression, ScriptCompressor, CompressionModule) but them seem to focus on combining or compressing only JS and CSS files (I've taken care of that already) or them are out of date ('06, '08 ages, we are '16 :)) or dont have up-to-date support.

Does anyone have (recently) found a way to achieve this? I only want to minify the webresource.axd file.

Thanks in advance.
Regards,

Comment: Just wondering if you might have found an answer to this yet as I'm trying to do the same thing...

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any obvious way of doing this. I've been looking for a solution to this as well. Let me know if you find a way.

Comment: Any idea or solution yet?